# Laravel route doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I am making basic route with controller but it doesnt work, I dont know why... Earyer worked for me but now doesnt...

Here is routes.php:

```
Route::get('/admin', array(
   'as' => 'admin-login',
   'uses' => 'AdminController@getAdminLogin'
));
```

Here is AdminController.php:

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

  public function getAdminLogin()
  {
    return View::make('admin.index');
  }
}
```

When I type **localhost/project/public/admin**... It goes to **localhost/admin**
Why?

Comment: Is it possible that you entered `localhost/project/public/admin/` with a trailing slash?

Comment: Hmm, well it could be many things... Probably the easiest way to fix it is by either using Laravel's webserver as Mustafa Ehsan mentioned or creating a virtual host for your probject so you can e.g. enter `project.dev/admin`

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use Laravel's own Web Server:

`php artisan serve`

And then, try this:

`http://localhost:8000/admin/`